# Export and import selected rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, import, export

I want to export specific data from my database and import it to another database tables. Mostly all the data is in one table, but there are some additional data in other tables. Most of other tables have only one record of the required data, but some tables have multiple required records. 
For example:

```
Case
------------------
ID name    status Sum 
1  first   2      854
2  second  4      NULL
3  third   6      951
4  fourth  2      1430

Payments
----------------------------
CaseID  Person  payment
1       Peter   35
1       Robert  48
3       Oscar   630
4       Rob     85
3       Oscar   130

Documents
-----------------------------
CaseId  DocTypeId  RegNr
1       3          14335
1       4          43456
1       1          34533
2       5          23454
2       3          35532
```

I need to export all cases which don't have status '6' and I need their payments and documents which may be more than one. I could join tables, but then those tables with multiple required records would create additional rows with the same column data.

```
With join I could get something like this
ID name   status Sum  CaseId Person payment CaseId DocTypeId RegNr
1  first  2      854  1      Peter  35      1      3         14335
1  first  2      854  1      Robert 48      1      4         43456
1  first  2      854  1      Peter  35      1      1         34533
```

Here you can see that like this I would get duplicate data. How can I get the data without duplicates? For example all data in one row?

I don't want to import duplicate data in a database as that would be really bad.
How can I achieve this?

I tried to look at some sql server possibilites but couldn't find what I need, so I suppose that I need to create my own script.

Comment: Can you post the query you are using and also your desired results? It's not clear what you are saying with the words `some` and `most`.

Comment: Case ID 1 is defined for Peter and Robert - so it's correct that - if you join over case ID - you receive two rows... please post the Join query you used.

Comment: I haven't created the whole query yet, just thinking how I can accomplish my needs as i can't see how to do that now.  
But for Case ID 1 that creates duplicates which will ruin data after import.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are getting the desired result in your join table output, except it gives you duplicates. You can easily ignore the duplicates and insert only one row in your output table.

Create a view that will give you the ranking of duplicates.

```
CREATE view View1 as(select *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(partition by names, status, some, person, payment Order by id) as rn from Your_join_table)
```

after that simply enter the rank 1 rows to your output table

```
select * into output_table from View1 where rn = 1
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I'm a little confused as I haven't used views (pretty new to databases). How could I import all required data by this? Wouldn't i need to do all rows manually? Can i import all the data without losing anything?

Comment: Views are the virtual table, so basically you are creating a temporary table to get all the rows you need. Once you have it, just get the unique rows you need. The join table you posted, does it have all the data you need? if yes, then follow my instructions. You are very close!

Comment: This is simplified version of what I need, I have to get data from more tables. I will try to create the whole query and see if I can get all required columns from all tables in my join table. Thank you for this, I will try to create it.